# PostgreSQL : How to pass a request to a function

Tags: postgresql, function, dll

I have a table of images and need to use a C image processing library to extract the n most relevant images from it. I try to figure out what parameters will be passed by prototyping the function in SQL (dummy):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clusterize(anyarray,integer) 
RETURNS TABLE(image bytea) AS $$
    SELECT * FROM $1
    ORDER BY random()
    LIMIT $2
$$ LANGUAGE SQL; -- will be C 

WITH subreq AS (
  SELECT decode(encode(thumbnail,'escape'), 'base64') "data",
    otherfields
  FROM images -- which actually is another WITH subrequest ...
)

SELECT clusterize(* FROM subreq,12)
```

generates a syntax error close to the $1. How to pass "subreq" results to the function ? In this case, does it mean that all images will be loaded in memory before calling the function, or is there an iterator mechanism ?

Is it simpler to decompose in two functions, an "addimage" function to call for each image and then a "clusterize(12)" that would return a table of  images ?

Answer (score 1):

Your function takes `anyarray` but `bytea` isn't an "array" in the usual PG sense. Since the table you're returning is of `bytea`, and you're not doing any sort of cast or transformation, is there any reason not to put the actual type as the parameter?

Regardless, if you want to `SELECT *` from an array, you need to `UNNEST` it to put it into table form.

So, your `clusterize` function now looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clusterize(anyarray,integer) 
RETURNS TABLE(image bytea) AS $$
    SELECT * FROM UNNEST($1)
    ORDER BY random()
    LIMIT $2
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
```

Now to create an actual array from the bytea data. There don't appear to be good bytea functions, so a bit of hackery does it:

```
WITH subreq AS (
        SELECT decode(encode(E'Th\\000omas'::bytea, 'escape'), 'escape') d
)
SELECT clusterize(ARRAY_AGG(SUBSTRING(d FROM g FOR 1)), 4)
FROM subreq, generate_series(1, LENGTH(d)) g
```

Result:

[image: result]

Now if we can change `clusterize` to take a `bytea`, we can hide that hacky code in there instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clusterize(bytea,integer) 
RETURNS TABLE(image bytea) AS $$
    SELECT SUBSTRING($1 FROM g FOR 1)
    FROM generate_series(1, LENGTH($1)) g
    ORDER BY random()
    LIMIT $2
$$ LANGUAGE SQL

WITH subreq AS (
        SELECT decode(encode(E'Th\\000omas'::bytea, 'escape'), 'escape') d
)
SELECT clusterize(d, 4)
FROM subreq
```

Result:

[image: result]